# Difference between sql subquery with and without FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. There are two sqls here.

```
-- sql #1, which contains a subquery with FROM 
UPDATE processing_client
SET updated_at = now()
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    from processing_client -- We have FROM here
    WHERE client_id = 1
    LIMIT 1
);

-- sql #2, which contains a subquery without FROM
UPDATE processing_client
SET updated_at = now()
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id -- We dont't have FROM here
    WHERE client_id = 1
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The scrpit to create related table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS processing_client
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    client_id int NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO processing_client(client_id, updated_at) VALUES (1, NOW()), (1, NOW());
```

In my opition, the two sqls were equivalent because I thought in `sql #2` the `processing_client` would implicitly be the FROM in the subquery.
However, they are totally different.
Affected rows for `sql #1` will always be **1**, which is expected.
Affected rows for `sql #2` will always be **2**, which is equal to the number of rows in the table.

**Questions:**
**1. Why are they different?**
**2. Why is the affected rows for `sql #2` NOT **1**, even though there is `LIMIT 1` in it?**
As far as I know, `sql #1` can be equivalently converted into two steps:

```
DECLARE _idList;
-- Step 1: get the id list that contains 1 element first
SELECT id into _idList
from processing_client -- We have FROM here
WHERE client_id = 1
LIMIT 1;
-- Step 2: use the id list in the condition
UPDATE processing_client
SET updated_at = now()
WHERE id IN _idList;
```

**3. Then what happend in `sql #2`? How is it translated?**

Comment: q1: The subqeury id/client_id belong to the subquery processing_client.

Comment: q2: The subqeury id/client_id belong to the outer query's processing_client.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the replies. Could you please explain what `belong to the outer query` means

Comment: Since the subquery has no table with those columns, you step out of the subquery and look for a table with the columns. (Repeat until found.) This is a reason why you should have different table aliases for each instance, and also _qualify_ all columns - to make code clear. (For yourself and also anyone else maintaining it decades later.)

Comment: @jarlh But the the table in the outer query is still processing_client, right? I don't understand what the difference is.  (I have added this as the third question in the post)

Answer (score 1):

A query or subquery without a `FROM` clause is just like selecting from a table with one row and no columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dual ();
INSERT INTO dual SELECT;
```

Now

```
SELECT 42;
```

will give the same result as

```
SELECT 42 FROM dual;
```

This only works if 42 is a constant, since the table does not have any columns:

```
SELECT col FROM dual;
ERROR:  column "col" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT col FROM dual;
               ^
```

It is pretty much what a `print` statement does in many other programming languages.

Now your subquery `(SELECT id WHERE client_id = 1 LIMIT 1)` does not throw an error, even though you reference some columns. Why is that so? The reason is that `id` and `client_id` are taken from the outer query. From the point of view of the inner query, they are just constants.

The `LIMIT 1` in your subquery does nothing, since a query without a `FROM` clause can only return one row anyway (for the nitpickers: I am ignoring set returning functions in the `SELECT` list here). So your condition is really equivalent to

```
WHERE id = CASE WHEN client_id = 1
                THEN id
                ELSE NULL
           END
```

which is semantically equivalent to

```
WHERE client_id = 1 AND id IS NOT NULL
```

because comparisons with NULL are never TRUE, and `id` is always equal to `id` (if it is not NULL).

Comment: It is a typo. Thanks, fixed.